# Jquery Mobile and Phonegap : can't choose a value in the select

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have this beautiful select menu made with jQuery Mobile, it's working perfectly when using a desktop browser. But one I build an android project and click the menu, it shows nothing.
More bizarre, when I change the displayed page, then the select options show up.
???
Is that normal?

```html
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" style="margin-top:0px;"> 
    <select name="select-pays" id="select-pays">
        <option>Pays</option>
        <option value="1">First choice</option>
        <option value="2">Second choice</option>
        <option value="3">Third choice</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is why, but technically you're required to have a label tag for the select, per the jQuery Mobile docs: "Set the for attribute of the label to match the ID of the select so they are semantically associated. It's possible to accessibly hide the label if it's not desired in the page layout, but we require that it is present in the markup for semantic and accessibility reasons"